# How to replace - (hyphens) with spaces in SSIS

Tags: database, automation, ssis

Since we receive the data in the form of excels. We are finding and replacing hyphens with space in excel (manual changes in the excel). Now the requirement is to make it automatic, to replace hyphens with spaces for the entire table (all columns) through SSIS, before they are loaded into tables.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have two columns :

[image]

This will you data entry in Excel Source component :

[image]

You can use a derived column and use REPLACE() function :

[image]